# Sort by attibute not working with Yes/No attribute type

Tags: magento-1.8, sorting

I am trying to sort the product listing by one attribute "best_seller". Attribute type is Yes/No , Now i need to sort product by the best_seller and need to show the best seller products set as Yes to appear first on the list. I already set this attribute to use for sorting from attribute settings.

I come to know that there is some issue with sorting when the attribute type is "Yes/No".
Can you anyone help me to fix this issue and or let me know if i am doing anything wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** The sorting doesn't work for Yes/No attributes.

**Long Answer:**
*The problem:*

When calling `addAttributeToSort` on a product collection, if the attribute has a source model then Magento calls `addValueSortToCollection` from that source model to sort the products.
The `Yes/No` attributes use the source model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean` that does not implement the method `addValueSortToCollection` For this model the method just returns `$this` without processing the collection.

*A possible solution:*
You can rewrite the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean` and add your `addValueSortToCollection` method. It should basically be the same code as it is in the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility` or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status` (not entirely sure about this) which is:

```
public function addValueSortToCollection($collection, $dir = 'asc')
{
    $attributeCode  = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $attributeId    = $this->getAttribute()->getId();
    $attributeTable = $this->getAttribute()->getBackend()->getTable();

    if ($this->getAttribute()->isScopeGlobal()) {
        $tableName = $attributeCode . '_t';
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array($tableName => $attributeTable),
                "e.entity_id={$tableName}.entity_id"
                    . " AND {$tableName}.attribute_id='{$attributeId}'"
                    . " AND {$tableName}.store_id='0'",
                array());
        $valueExpr = $tableName . '.value';
    }
    else {
        $valueTable1 = $attributeCode . '_t1';
        $valueTable2 = $attributeCode . '_t2';
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array($valueTable1 => $attributeTable),
                "e.entity_id={$valueTable1}.entity_id"
                    . " AND {$valueTable1}.attribute_id='{$attributeId}'"
                    . " AND {$valueTable1}.store_id='0'",
                array())
            ->joinLeft(
                array($valueTable2 => $attributeTable),
                "e.entity_id={$valueTable2}.entity_id"
                    . " AND {$valueTable2}.attribute_id='{$attributeId}'"
                    . " AND {$valueTable2}.store_id='{$collection->getStoreId()}'",
                array()
            );
            $valueExpr = $collection->getConnection()->getCheckSql(
                $valueTable2 . '.value_id > 0',
                $valueTable2 . '.value',
                $valueTable1 . '.value'
            );
    }

    $collection->getSelect()->order($valueExpr . ' ' . $dir);
    return $this;
}
```

[Explanation provided here also for a similar issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14411/146)

Comment: Facing Same problem, and implemented @Marius solution: rewrite `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean` class but it shows me error `Source model "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean" not found for attribute "set_as_featured"` with stack trace also. `set_as_featured` is in global scope with used in listing product and sorting `Yes` in backend options. please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Marius, I have implemented your code but when I am using `$collection->addAttributeToSort('featured', 'desc');` then it is not returning correct result. For `featured` attribute I have set `global scope, used in listing product yes and sorting No`, because I don't want to add this option with sort-by options. Is there any other setting which are missing here?

Comment: I don't know if you are missing something. the code above worked for me.